# Use mplayer as an xscreensaver?

Tags: screensaver, mplayer, xscreensaver

Wanting to run a video as my screensaver, I ran into problems configuring it appropriately. I am summarizing the solution here in Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Background

Screensaver programs are configured in `~/.xscreensaver`. It is modified when using `xscreensaver-demo`, which under XFCE is named just `Screensaver` in the Whisker Menu.

To add a program, go to the setting `programs:`, which should look something like

```
mode:       one
selected:   0

textMode:   url
textLiteral:    XScreenSaver
textFile:   
textProgram:    fortune
textURL:    https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:NewPages&feed=rss
programs:                                     \
  GL:                           superquadrics -root                         \n\
                                attraction -root                            \n\
                                blitspin -root                              \n\
-                               greynetic -root                             \n\
                                helix -root                                 \n\
                                hopalong -root                              \n\
...
```

- `mode: one` means, that a fixed screensaver is used, not e.g. a randomly selected one or just a blank screen. It is the most appropriate setting for the “play a video as screensaver” use-case.
- `selected: 0` means that the first entry in the list `programs` is used. The man-page explicitly says to set it through `xscreensaver-demo` instead of manually, but when adding a custom program at the top of the list, setting this to `0` is a good-enough option.
- `text*:` options are not really relevant to this question, but are there by default.
- `programs:` is a list of commands, separated by `\n`. The trailing `\` just means line-continuation in order for the long list not to be on a single line. The format is

  ```
  "PROGRAM NAME" COMMAND ARGUMENTS... \n
  ```

  where `"PROGRAM NAME"` is optional, the `"` are required if it is given. When not specified, the name displayed in `xscreensaver-demo` is derived from `COMMAND`, e.g. `helix` being displayed as `Helix`. Programs, whose command is not actually available, will not be listed in `xscreensaver-demo`, so if the video player command does not show up, something likely was typed incorrectly.

#### 2. Configuration example

Let’s say there is a video file `/home/user/black_hole.mp4`. Then adding it as a properly named screensaver option, the `programs:` setting is changed to

```
programs:                                                                     \
                  "Black Hole"  mplayer -loop 0 -nosound -fixed-vo            \
                                  -wid $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW                   \
                                  /home/user/black_hole.mp4                 \n\
                                maze -root                                  \n\
  GL:                           superquadrics -root                         \n\
                                attraction -root                            \n\
                                blitspin -root                              \n\
                                ...
```

Don’t sweat the use of well-placed line-continuation. The screensaver programs will read and rewrite this file anyway, causing any custom formatting to be lost, and command and names to be aligned roughly as displayed above.

In the given example,

- `"Black Hole"` is the display-name for the configured screen-saver. Without this double-quoted string, it would just be called `Mplayer` in `xscreensaver-demo`.
- `-loop 0` tells *mplayer* to loop the video indefinitely.
- `-nosound`, well, disables the output of sound. Usually preferable for screensavers.
- `-fixed-vo` is needed, because by default `mplayer` reinitializes the playback window after each video. For the screen-saver looping a single video, this means that there will be flickering when the video starts over, as opposed to smooth playback. With `-fixed-vo`, smooth playback is achieved, but forum threads mentioned that it might crash the program on some systems. If you see only a black screen, or the video plays only once, it might be worth trying, if this setting is the cause.
- `-wid $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW` is needed in order for the video play back to be actually visible on the screen-saver. I would have expected the `-rootwin` option to have the same effect, but it doesn’t.

#### 3. Multiple video files.

If you want multiple video files to be played, simply add all the file names. The command is executed through a shell, so also wildcards can be used, e.g. `/home/user/myscreensavervideos/*`.

In such cases, adding the `-shuffle` option may be desirable too.

#### 4. `mplayer` vs `mpv`

When looking for ways to use the video as screensaver, I came mostly over solutions using `mpv`. I chose `mplayer` instead, because it was already installed on my system. This is an important criterion, when being on a workstation, where you don’t have root access.